# Snap Store is not coming up in UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: snap, 20.04

System Details:
Upgrade system: Ubuntu 18.04.04 - 19.10 - 20.04

I am not able to bring up snap-store and when I am trying to fire from terminal, it shows following error on the same.

`:~$ snap-store 
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_8k8wWU//dev: No such file or directory`

Can someone throw light on this issue?

Ps: Does 20.04 upgrade is buggy?

Comment: If you had done a fresh install it would work ok. As is, (upgrades) even if it started would likely be deficient. You could try `sudo snap remove snap-store`. Then in ~/snap delete the snap-store folder if there. Then install the beta version, it may work ok.. `sudo snap install snap-store --beta` See here, comments 114,115 https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/is-ubuntu-software-going-to-be-remove-for-snap-snap-store/14542/115

Comment: Thank you Doug! Appreciate your response. Unfortunately, it didnt worked.

snap-store removed
r:~$ sudo rm -r ~/snap/
r:~$ sudo snap install snap-store --beta
snap-store (beta) 3.36.0-75-g02a9109 from Canonical✓ installed

:~$ snap-store
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev /tmp/snap.rootfs_GvnWs9//dev: No such file or directory

Comment: As it turns out there is a convoluted command to get the 20.04 release version of snap-store. Though that doesn't seem to be your issue.., can you install any snap?? If not maybe remove then re-install snapd & start over. The command to change existing is `sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-20.04` , the command for a fresh install of snap-store is the same, just replace refresh with install. At some future point they''ll update latestest/stable to this version so above command isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments and some pointers on the same. Still looks buggy(sluggish in accessing). As you said, will wait for the stable version. Thanks once again!

Comment: I found that snap store is broken on 20.04, even if you got it to work, its software keep crashing and there are a lot of packaging issues, better download the package from its source than using the snap store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following things done to restore snap-store, but still looks buggy.

1. Uninstall snapd and snap-store
2. Install snapd and snap-store
3. Update existing candidate
   **sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-20.04**  (Thank you @doug for the steps)

I could get back snap-store on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does not work: no updates available

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Can you please try restarting the machine? It worked for me.