# System proxy for snap-store in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, snap, proxy

I upgraded my work PC from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.
I always work behind a proxy. I added proxy configuration in:

- /etc/environment
- /etc/profile.d/env.sh
- /etc/apt/apt.conf (for APT)

Before the upgrade, I installed some packages using Snap. After the upgrade, there seem to be a problem with my proxy configuration and Snap application: snap store can't connect to get updates from https://odrs.gnome.org/1.0/reviews/api, Skype starts but fails to connect, Postman hangs on forever on request until, in teh proxy section o settings, I add a custom proxy configuration ("use system proxy" was already selected).

[image: snap store error]

I've already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1146047/1084897), but with no luck.

EDIT: I tried also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231735/snap-store-is-not-coming-up-in-ubuntu-20-04?rq=1), now Ubuntu Software starts but it doesn't work well: the main page is empty, and "search" is stuck...
[image: ubuntu software]
[image]