# Snapstore not starting

Tags: 20.04, snap, snap-store

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.
When I'm launching Snapstore, nothing happens. This is a new behaviour, worked fine about a week ago.

When I launch it via terminal using

```
snap-store
```

It says:

```
Gtk Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

But when I do (as written here: [Failed to load module “canberra-gtk-module” .... but already installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed)):

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

it says:

```
libcanberra-gtk3-module is already the latest version (0.30-7ubuntu1).
libcanberra-gtk-module is already the latest version (0.30-7ubuntu1).
```

**Edit**
I made a reboot and it says now (additionally to the canberra-gtk-module error):

```
"Memory access error (memory dump written)"
```

(might sound a bit different, as I'm using the german version and the message in german is: Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)

Comment: The Gtk failed doesn't usually cause the snap-store not to load.  You might want to look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231735/snap-store-is-not-coming-up-in-ubuntu-20-04 as you might need to remove and reinstall the snap-store to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-store-is-not-starting/31536/13

There's a problem with revision 558 of the snap-store that is currently the stable one. But the bug is fixed in the edge-version (currently 592). So you can try install the edge-version:

`sudo snap refresh --edge snap-store`

to switch back to stable, once the fixed 592 revision has migrated to stable, you can then run:

`sudo snap refresh --stable snap-store`